# How to get Maximum 3 Value?

Tags: crystal-reports

How to get Maximum 3 value in Crystal Report.

This is my Result

[image: All value show]

But my requirement is

[image: maximum 3 value show]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built- in Crystal Reports.

1. Select **Insert | Summary**
2. Choose the field to summarize
3. In Calculate this summmary choose function "Nth largest, N is" and type 1, 2, 3

[Nth largest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQcDi.png)

Another way is to use the NthLargest function inside formula editor:

```html
NthLargest (1, {SalesOrderHeader.SubTotal}) + NthLargest (2, {SalesOrderHeader.SubTotal}) + NthLargest (3, {SalesOrderHeader.SubTotal})
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a SQL Expression (`SEQ_INV`):

```
(
  row_number() OVER (ORDER BY OrderNo DESC)
)
```

Add this text to the record-selection formula:

```
{%SEQ_INV}<4
```